# Android and iOS logos on my website

Tags: copyright, android, ios

Can I insert Android and iOS logos to sponsor an App on my website? Or is it considered copyright infringement?

Comment: Hi Sara, could you please clarify.. do you mean the Android logo and any of Apples logos or the logos of specific apps available on Android and iOS?

Comment: Sorry CAI, i mean that I wanna sponsor that my App is Available on Apple Store and Play Store, so I would insert their logos like happen in the majority of websites.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that if you are currently listed as an available app on both of these platforms then you are allowed to display their icons. These brands often have usage policies that you need to agree to before downloading them, so doing a Google image search and using the icons from there is not the best way to go about it.

Plus going to the dedicated site gives you many more options, as with the example from Google below

https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/badges/

Answer (score 1):

For iOS, you should use the **App Store Badge**.

- You can download the badge and read the usage guidelines here:
  [App Store Marketing Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/marketing/guidelines/#)

For Android (I'm assuming you mean the Google Play Store), you should use the **Google Play badge**

- You can download the Google Play badge and read the usage guidelines here: [Google Play badge page](https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/badges/)

---

More general info on using Apple trademarks can be found here:

- [Guidelines for Using Apple Trademarks and Copyrights](http://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/guidelinesfor3rdparties.html)
- [Apple Trademark List](http://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/trademark/appletmlist.html)

More general info on using Android trademarks can be found here:

- [Android Brand Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/brand.html)