# Using Play Store badges and F logos, etc. on printed material

Tags: print-design, website-design, copyright, android

There are established guidelines about the use of the Play Store logo, Facebook F logo, etc. in websites, etc.

There is a related question on this topic [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/67998/android-and-ios-logos-on-my-website). Google play store has its guidelines [here](https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/badges/). Guidelines for Facebook, etc. can be easily found on their sites.

I would like to understand if I can use these logos on printed material as well. Nowhere on these "guidelines" webpages could I find any information about using these logos in print. Should I assume what is written for webpages to apply equally to printed matter?

For example, if I have a new gourmet chocolate shop (and a matching app and FB page), and on my business card (and other printed promo material) I want to include the corresponding logos to remind people that my app/page can also be found on Play store, App Store, as a website (with the Google Chrome logo) and on Facebook, etc. etc.

Is this allowed?

*PS: I am new on this specific SE, but I believe graphic design applies generally to all graphic design (online or offline media).*

Comment: Both facebook and google have request forms to request permission. The best idea is to contact them via these forms if you can't find information specific to your use-case. We can't give you legal advice here.

Comment: @BillyKerr i think your answer was OK. Is there any particular reason you wish not to answer?

Comment: @joojaa not sure, but I think it might be off-topic. What do you think? I could undelete it.

Comment: No i think its ok especcialy if you add a general comment. I would add that using webpage usage on print form is usually not OK. That covers the general question and then you point out that specifically facebook and google disallow usage asked about, presumably print usage instructions are in separate guidelines to those who have been vetted for such use.

Comment: @joojaa OK. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask yourself..

Do you *really* need a Facebook logo on a business card?
Don't you think Facebook users, who are aware of your company name and are interested, would NOT search for you on Facebook?

Facebook has become ubiquitous. One would *not* put a Yellow Pages logo next to your phone number. It's the *same thing* essentially.

All this all holds true for the Play Store/App Store as well. if someone's interested, they'll search..

**In printed material** (*especially* a business card) **all you need is *your* website URL.** Then on *your* website you can link to Facebook/Play Store/App Store/whatever. Human nature would be to visit a business' website first.. then see if they have a Facebook page.. an app.. etc.

These types of logos and monikers are really only necessary in printed materials when those materials are specifically advertising that aspect. I mean, clearly if you run an ad about your shop you want to have the Play Store logo so people know the shop is there as well. If you create a sales letter or brochure, you may want them there as well. However, the primary function of any *business card* is to convey contact information a bunch of random logos and urls will **not** drive people to those places. Putting myriad urls and logos on a business card does *nothing* be cause brand confusion and visual chaos. Put these logos and links on *your* web site where they actually work not on other printed materials **especially** any business cards. Really, *never* on a business card.

Business cards should *not* be "advertising billboards".

Comment: The goal is to *remind* them to do that (search the app on the play store). Yes, you are right that those promo materials are specifically advertizing that aspect. About the business card, there are two sides to it - front and back. One side of it will be clean (name, company name,) like it should. The other side can contain some of these logos, no?

Comment: My personal opinion is no. It devalues the brand. Advertising doesn't really belong on any business card.

Comment: "devalues the brand" very good point. So, summary: those logos/badges belong on the promo material, not on the card. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you can't assume that brand guidelines for use on web pages will also apply to print.  I have managed to find information about using them in some print cases (which might not apply to your specific use-case):

This [page on use of google logos/trademarks](https://www.google.com/permissions/logos-trademarks/) says:

> Google typically does not allow third-party use of our logo or brand features to create paraphernalia or swag.

The [facebook brand guidelines](https://facebookbrand.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Facebook-Brand-Assets-Guide-1.pdf) say:

> Facebook does not permit or license any of its assets for use on
> merchandise or other products, such as clothing, hats or mugs.

Both facebook and google have request forms for brand use permission. The best idea is to contact them via these forms if you can't find information specific to your use-case. We can't give you legal advice here.